# OpenSSL smime verify failed with right certificate and signature

Tags: openssl, signature, actionscript-2, edi, smime

I receive encrypted and signed smime message. 
Decrypting is ok, data seems to be correct.

```
openssl.exe smime -decrypt -in %1 -out %1_signed.txt -inkey myPrivate.pem
```

But on verifying signature stage I get error.

```
openssl.exe smime -verify -CAfile senderCACert.pem -certfile senderCert.pem -in %1 -out %1_plain

Verification failure
7600:error:21071065:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_signatureVerify:digest failure:./crypto/pkcs7/pk7_doit.c:9
48:
7600:error:21075069:PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:signature failure:./crypto/pkcs7/pk7_smime.c:312:
```

Sender both certificates (CA cert and client cert) should be ok.

I think that openssl can produce specific symbols during decrypting like new-line character or something else that doesn't exist in source message. Or it could process non-standard algorythm (at least as far as I know openssl has non-standard storage format of private keys)

I use openssl 0.9.8h. And smime message on other side is formed by "webMethods EDI version 6.5" software (it is AS2 server for processing EDI messages).

What is the reason of this error?

Could you advise another smime tool to try?

Answer (score 2):

[INTRO]
Thanks for your question ;-) I have finally taken some time to formalize how I can debug my AS2 communication using OpenSSL.

[BACKGROUND] (1) I am developing BabelAS2 - http://code.google.com/p/babelas2/ - an open source VBScript implementation of the EDIINT AS2 (RFC 4130) standard transport protocol. I am using CAPICOM as the Cryptography library. (2) I wanted to check how I can use "Win32 OpenSSL v0.9.8q" from http://www.shininglightpro.com to debug the cryptography part ;-)

[SOLUTION#1] Decrypt the HTTP payload:

1. Manually add the following text on top of the dump of the HTTP payload

   ```
   MIME-Version: 1.0
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
   Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
   [CRLF]
   ```
2. Then, you can use:

   ```
   openssl smime -decrypt -inkey "Server.pair-of-keys.pem" -in "HTTP-Payload.encrypted.txt.with-manually-added-header.txt" -out "decrypted.with-OpenSSL.txt"
   ```

[SOLUTION#2] Very the signature of the decrypted message:

1. Just use

   ```
   openssl.exe smime -verify -in "decrypted.with-OpenSSL.txt" -CAfile "Client.cer"
   ```

Let me know if it helped you...

Comment: Thanks. I already solved this problem and describe it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975612/openssl-treats-smime-message-with-content-type-application-edi-as-text-and-chan

Comment: @Donz, thanks for your feedback and your link, if I ever have problem with 'Application/EDI' I will remember it ;-)